# Problema com Case Sensitive

Tags: php

Estou construindo uma pequena aplicação em MVC, para fins didáticos, fiz a maior parte no Windows, quando passei meus scripts para o Elementary Os, muitos erros foram aparecendo, de inclusão de arquivos e etc, esses erros decorrem por causa do Case-Sensitive, oque posso fazer para consertar isso?

Comment: Estava pesquisando e vi que em alguns fóruns que redirecionar urls com htaccess é uma boa, mas como faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente, padronize os nomes e escreva sempre igual tanto nos códigos fonte quanto nos arquivos. O jeito, no seu caso, é revisar o código, e consertar.

Se for uma "medida desesperada", o que for coisa sua mesmo, passe tudo pra minúscula, para não ter que pensar muito.

Mantenha *camelcase* só o que for biblioteca de terceiros, senão quando for atualizar, vai se complicar de novo.

Inclusive, evite sempre nomes de arquivo com acentos e espaços, que são outra fonte de problemas.

> Importante: soluções que usam `.htaccess` servem para arrumar links que o usuário final que está navegando no site digitou com *casing* errado, e não para arrumar nomes digitados errados pelo próprio autor do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

De uma lida sobre padrões de projeto, lá você vai aprender mais sobre padronização na escrita de nomes de classes, onde a primeira letra de cada palavra começa com maiúsculo, e muitos outros.
Seguindo estes padrões você não terá nenhum problema ao migrar seus sistemas de servidor.
Lembrando que todas as distribuições linux ou linux based são case sensitive, enquanto o windows não é.

Comment: Os nomes de classes seguem padrões de projetos. Tem uma regra para a escrita de nomes de classes como eu disse acima, a primeira letra de cada palavra deve iniciar sempre com letra maiúscula. EX: class UsuariosAtivos.